# $\forall x \in M_1$, $f(x) = g(x)$ for the given conditions of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Say that $(M_1, d_1)$ and $(M_2, d_2)$ are metric spaces, and that $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions from $M_1$ to $M_2$.

Suppose that $A$ is dense in $(M_1, d_1)$ and that for all $a \in A$, $f(a) = g(a)$.

By dense, I mean that $(\forall x \in M_1)(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists a \in A)(d_1(x,a) < 
\epsilon)$

I'm trying to prove that for all $x \in M_1$, $f(x) = g(x)$

I think the functions f and g are determined by their values on the dense subsets of their respective domains, because they are continuous functions from a metric space to another metric space. Would the proof follow directly from the second line above or is it more involved then that?

Comment: Yes, it pretty much follows. For completeness' sake, perhaps try explaining why $f$ and $g$ are determined by their values on $A$, and show that $f(x)=g(x)$ when $x\notin A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h(x)=d(g(x),f(x))$.  This function is continuous since it is the composition of continuous functions.  If $h(y) \neq 0$ then by continuity there is some $U$ such that $h(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in U$.  But since $A$ is dense there is some $a \in U \cap A$.  Hence $h(a) = 0$ contradicting part of the definition of $U$.

Comment: I must be missing something. Why is U being brought in at all? Does it represent a placeholder that has the same properties as $M_1$? How does this demonstrate equality for $f$ and $g$ in $M_1$?

Comment: The set of points where g does not equal f is open.  If this open set is not empty then by density $A$ must enter this open set at some point $a$.  But we assumed that $f(a)=g(a)$, which is a contradiction.  The $U$ in my proof is the open set you're looking for.